# "Reported Web Forgery" message on one install of Firefox but not another

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security, phishing

On my 64bit Windows 7 machine running latest version of 32bit Firefox I received the following message when visiting a URL from an email...

[image]

in order to check it out further, I loaded firefox on a VM running Windows 7 32bit and latest version of firefox. Then I entered the offensive URL. Nothing. No message.

I checked the security settings but they are the same. What gives?

---

EDIT:

The security options I assume it is referring to are in the Tools Menu->Options->Security

- Block reported attack sites
- Block reported web forgeries

They are both enabled in both browsers.

Comment: clicking a link in email and typing what you believe to be the same address  is not the same, believe what you see the first time, email is the number one way to infect machines with obfuscated malicious links.

Answer (score 0):

Not long after posting the question the browser in the VM starting to report the same thing.

From "How does Phishing and Malware Protection work in Firefox?" located [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work#w_how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work-in-firefox)

> Phishing and Malware Protection works by checking the sites that you
>   visit against lists of reported phishing, unwanted software and
>   malware sites. These lists are automatically **downloaded and updated
>   every 30 minutes** or so when the Phishing and Malware Protection
>   features are enabled. The technical details of the safe-browsing
>   protocol are also publicly available.